# Prestashop 1.7 how to edit $stylesheets smarty variable

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to improve my Google PageSpeed Insigths. In category "Preload key requests" I can see such result:

```
…css/199038f….woff2
4500 ms
…css/19c1b86….woff2
4230 ms
…css/570eb83….woff2
4080 ms
```

Those files are in classic/assets/css/, anyways I couldn't find the place where it's added to code, so I could fix those links to preload. I found a file stylesheets.tpl in classic/templates/_partials/, and I've changed:

```
{foreach $stylesheets.external as $stylesheet}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$stylesheet.uri}" type="text/css" media="{$stylesheet.media}">
{/foreach}
```

to

```
{foreach $stylesheets.external as $stylesheet}
  <link rel="preload" as="style" href="{$stylesheet.uri}" media="{$stylesheet.media}">
{/foreach}
```

It worked for the insights, no more warning about it but unfortunately it's breaking website (acting like there were no styles at all). I tried a few more combinations like: as="font", as="font" type="woff2" but it didn't help.

My plan for now is to delete those three css files from $stylesheets.external and add them manualy in head.tpl but I can't locate where to find this object?

How to edit $stylesheets variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the stylesheets variable, assigned in FrontController.php

Function name display()

File path : classes/controller/FrontController.php

Answer (score 0):

Indeed mentioned function in FrontController contains:

```
public function display()
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'layout' => $this->getLayout(),
            'stylesheets' => $this->getStylesheets(),
            'javascript' => $this->getJavascript(),
            'js_custom_vars' => Media::getJsDef(),
            'notifications' => $this->prepareNotifications(),
        ));

        $this->smartyOutputContent($this->template);

        return true;
    }
```

So I searched this getStylesheets(), thats it:

```
    public function getStylesheets()
    {
        $cssFileList = $this->stylesheetManager->getList();

        if (Configuration::get('PS_CSS_THEME_CACHE')) {
            $cssFileList = $this->cccReducer->reduceCss($cssFileList);
        }

        return $cssFileList;
    }
```

Then searched for stylesheetManager etc, but anyways it's not that place where certain stylesheets being added to this variable (neither in StylesheetManager.php). I need to find a file (or so), where all those stylsheets being registered/added to this stylesheets variable. Does anyone know where could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I have explain, how you can modify display function and assign new array in stylesheets. Please check below:

```
public function display()
            {

            $arrStylessheets =  $this->getStylesheets();

            print_r($arrStylessheets);//check those stylesheets keys here

            unset($arrStylessheets['<those stylesheets here>']);
          
           
            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'layout' => $this->getLayout(),
                'stylesheets' => $arrStylessheets,// pass new array stylesheet  
                'javascript' => $this->getJavascript(),
                'js_custom_vars' => Media::getJsDef(),
                'notifications' => $this->prepareNotifications(),
            ));
    
            $this->smartyOutputContent($this->template);
    
            return true;
        }
```